# \whiledo not working when using it to generate table

Tags: tables, longtable, counters, loops, ifthenelse

I'm trying to use `\whiledo` (contained in the `ifthen` package) to automate the creation of a table. The idea—more or less—is that by setting a value `\colnum` to a number x, I can make a table with x+1 columns whose headers are the numbers up to x. So for instance, setting the value of `\colnum` to 5 would generate the following table:

[image]

I've been using the code below to go about this, but I keep getting the following errors:

1. Incomplete `\iffalse`; all text was ignored after line 20.
2. Extra `\else`.
3. Extra `\fi`.
4. Extra alignment tab has been changed to `\cr`.

Here's the code, with the result below:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcounter{loopcheck}
\setcounter{loopcheck}{1}

\begin{document}
\def\colnum{5} %Sets number of columns
\begin{longtable}{|c|*{\colnum}{|c}|} %Makes table with correct number of columns
\hline
\whiledo{\colnum>\theloopcheck}%
{&\theloopcheck%Tabs forward one column and prints the number stored in the counter
\refstepcounter{loopcheck}}%Increases the counter by one
\setcounter{loopcheck}{0}\\\hline%Sets the counter to zero once everything's done with
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

In addition, the table that gets generated looks like this:

[image]

with no border or anything on the right and two extra iterations of the loop, *but* instead of a tab, the iterations are separated by spaces. I've tried changing the `&` to a `\\` and various other things, and they all work fine, but for some reason the `&` and only the `&` is causing problems. Any idea why? Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Your loop starts in a column and ends in another one: this is not possible.

You need to build the entire row before delivering it.

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcounter{loopcheck}

\newcommand{\firstrow}{%
  \def\firstrowtemp{}%
  \setcounter{loopcheck}{0}%
  \whiledo{\colnum>\value{loopcheck}}{%
    \stepcounter{loopcheck}%
    \edef\firstrowtemp{\firstrowtemp&\theloopcheck}%
  }\firstrowtemp
}

\begin{document}


\def\colnum{5} %Sets number of columns
\begin{longtable}{|c|*{\colnum}{|c}|} %Makes table with correct number of columns
\hline
\firstrow \\
\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

A simpler method with `expl3` syntax:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\firstrow}{}
 {
  \int_step_function:nN { \colnum } \genconf_firstrow:n
 }

\cs_new:Nn \genconf_firstrow:n { & #1 }

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}


\def\colnum{5} %Sets number of columns
\begin{longtable}{|c|*{\colnum}{|c}|} %Makes table with correct number of columns
\hline
\firstrow \\
\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

With `\int_step_function:nN` the function `\genconf_firstrow:n` is called with arguments the numbers from 1 to the stated upper bound.

[image]